# Is there any way to validate that a request to .NET Framework Web API is from our hosted portal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

I am using .NET Framework Web API, and I need to verify the API calls are from my hosted portal end.
Is there any method to validate request and block requests?
I used CORS to validate, and I don't know if that is the best practice to verify.

Comment: What do you mean with 'hosted portal end'?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Web application

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. if you want to verify the API calls from your hosted portal and block other domain the best way is to use the **Cross Origin Resource Sharing `(CORS)`**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: AllowPortalDomain,
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("http://PortalDomain.com");
                          });
    });

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
app.UseCors(AllowPortalDomain);
...
}
```

You can enable Cross-Origin Requests per controller or action:

```
[EnableCors("AllowPortalDomain")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult yourAPI(){...}
```

for more information see this link [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#enable-cors-in-mvc)

hope this helps!